# Cannot access VisualSVN server by the URLs supplied in Getting Started guide

Tags: svn, netbeans-8, visualsvn-server

I am a new user and admin of a VisualSVN server. After reading https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/ I tried pasting the default repo URL into the browser: https://svn.example.com/svn/ After several attempts failed with a 404 error, the 4th or 5th attempt redirected to https://svn.example.com/!/#

Next I tried connecting Netbeans to the repo and it only worked when the URL was

https://svn.example.com/!/#reponame/projectname

but did not work with

https://svn.example.com/svn/reponame/projectname

Are the URLs from Getting Started supposed to work and I just botched something during installation? Or am I supposed to use the `/!/#` piece?

Comment: `svn.example.com` is a sample URL. Use the real and correct URL.

Comment: Do you seriously believe I was using example.com?

Comment: I did at first, but not now. :)

Comment: I agree this is a horrible question to ask and it should be slugged by everyone driving by. How dare I question VisualSVN at all 456?!

Answer (score 1):

- The URL that looks like `https://svn.example.com/svn/` can be passed to web browser or TortoiseSVN 1.7+ client only. This URL leads to the list of repositories that can be viewed with TortoiseSVN 1.7+ only and with web browsers.
- When using a web browser and accessing the collection of repositories, you are getting automatically redirected to the HTLM5-based web interface which has the URL like `https://svn.example.com/!/#`.
- In NetBeans or any Subversion client, enter the URL that points to a repository `https://svn.example.com/svn/reponame/` or a specific branch of or trunk, whatever. Like this `https://svn.example.com/svn/reponame/myproject/branches/feature-X`

Check VisualSVN Server event log if you still get any errors.

Comment: This kind of contradicts my experience.

Comment: @ajeh tell about your experience in such case, please.

Comment: it's in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen that behaviour, on the server side you can copy the correct URL at any folder in your repo, but at the web page on Mozilla, Chrome, or any other you just get the damn `https://anysite.com/!/#..`, if users want to share a specific URL all they saw is `https://anysite.com/!/#` and with that you can't make a proper checkout!

Comment: Solved?

https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00102/